# Autofac 3.5.0.0 - Registering Controllers automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I was using Autofac 3.0.0.0 and I used this code snippet to register controllers automatically instead of registering one by one.

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

After updating to Autofac 3.5.0.0 I noticed the method RegisterControllers doesn't exist anymore.
Any idea how I can accomplish this with the new version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RegisterControllers` method is not part of Autofac, it is part of [the Autofac MVC library](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration). Check to see that you haven't accidentally lost the reference to that library when upgrading the core library.

Comment: That's it @Peter. Yesterday I noticed that! Thanks a million